# Negative Feed on Electrical Lines

Tags: mains

I live in a New York apt and I woke up last Saturday (5/30/15) because our power went out at about 7:30 am. A quick check with the bldg's doorman revealed that it was just our apt and not a total blackout as I first thought it was. Our maintenance guy came and checked our circuit breaker using a simple power tester. He seemed to know what the problem was and proceeded to explain that we have a negative feed problem. When I asked him what a negative feed was he tried to explain it this way: "In an old apartment, sometimes one of the 2 live wires 'dies' and when that happens your appliances consumes power even when they are turned off. And that's what's called a negative feed. He also said something about 1 of wires as positive and the other, negative." He then said that he can revive the dead wire by putting a device. The whole thing will probably cost us a thousand but he can do it for $250. He also said that the same situation happened to one of the tenants in the building a week ago.

His explanation was vague and theory-wise, I've never heard of such a thing. I'm a graduate of electronics and communication eng'g back in 1982 in my home country. While I know much has changed and I haven't put what I learned into practice, his explanation was highly suspicious and I immediately thought that I'm being scammed.

Am I? Thanks in advance.

Horace

Comment: Wanna buy a bridge?

Comment: If you are renting, your landlord should be responsible for fixing this. Let him get scammed.

Comment: It's a scam, as the others say. At least that he may hav disconnected your power in order to attempt to obtain money from you. How you deal with this is up to you, but regardless, he's talking rubbish and is 'up to no good'. If he's doing this to you then he's probably preying on any gullible and fragile people he can find. The doorman is meant to be some form of (minor) defence against problems - not a source of them. Having written the above I've convinced myself that in that situation I'd feel the need to have him dealt with by landlord and/or police.

Comment: Why is it a scam.... because it's NY

Comment: First call the landlord, then the police. It sounds like a scam. The fact that this is in NY City makes it virtually certain. (Even if it were not a scam, it's the landlord's obligation to make sure you have power in your apartment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a scam, as the others say. At least consider that he, or two working together,  may have disconnected your power in order to attempt to obtain money from you.
How you deal with this is up to you, but regardless, he's talking rubbish and is 'up to no good'. If he's doing this to you then he's probably preying on any gullible and fragile people he can find. The doorman is meant to be some form of (minor) defence against problems - not a source of them. Having written the above I've convinced myself that in that situation I'd feel the need to have him dealt with by landlord and/or police

---

> our power went out at about 7:30 am.

When did the doorman start work. Does he know the maintenance guy.

> we have a negative feed problem.

The term "negative feed' has meaning in some contexts but none in this one.

> "In an old apartment, sometimes one of the 2 live wires 'dies'

They are alive or dead. If dead, just repair.

> and when that happens your appliances consumes power even when they are turned off.

Rubbish / malarkey / fabrication / lies / ...
Do I make myself clear? :-)

> And that's what's called a negative feed.

And again.

> He also said something about 1 of wires as positive and the other, negative."

Wires on one phase can be phase and neutral / live and ground etc.
Postive and negative are DC circuit terms and suggest incompetence on the part of the scammer.

> He then said that he can revive the dead wire by putting a device. The whole thing will probably cost us a thousand but he can do it for $250. He also said that the same situation happened to one of the tenants in the building a week ago.

Wanna buy a bridge?
Oh. Wait. Someone already offered you one in the comments :-)
ie this is a scam. And what would the landlord say about this bill. And is this man the landlord's official fix it man? and if so, for how much longer?

> His explanation was vague and theory-wise, I've never heard of such a thing. I'm a graduate of electronics and communication eng'g back in 1982 in my home country. While I know much has changed and I haven't put what I learned into practice, his explanation was highly suspicious and I immediately thought that I'm being scammed.

Am I?

Only if you want to be.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I'm also leaning towards this being a scam. But I'm also trying to exhaust all possible scenarios before "righting this wrong". There's a comment from Vijay about a leakage protection relay and I want to make my case tight before I confront those who are responsible. Thanks again.

Comment: @HoraceFriend A "leakage protection relay" / ELCB / GFI / ... is like a fuse or contactor or circuit breaker that disconnects the power to a circuit when a fault occurs BUT unlike the fuse/breaker which trip on gross overcurrent, the ELCB (earth leak circuit breaker) trips when there is a SMALL amount of imbalance between go and return circuits. This happens when some of the current going "out" on one lead does not come "back" on the other because there is leakage to earcth. BUT they protect a circuit beyond where they are installed - not by insertion in a power outlet etc. They go eg ....

Comment: .... on a switchboard where a fuse usually goes and protect ONLY the circuit they are in series with. Energy flows through them when they are on and is blocked when they are off. They are usually equipped one per wiring circuit in place of eg a fuse. They do not go in a random outlet and do not cost $250 -  and not $1000 either. | In random sockets you may install a listening bug, or a piece of scam pretend rubbish that increases your fire risk. Best you could manage is a spike absorber/suppressor that reduces power spikes on the circuit it is connected to - but it does not do what ....

Comment: ... your man's magic device does and usually does not cost $250. (You CAN get $250 ones but you can also get crystals tat make your HiFi allegedly sound better and ...). | It's a scam. Alas.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a scam.. but being an engineer pl. ref. to the ammended electrical wiring regulation for new constructions wherein earthing has been made mandetory. If your building is old and if in the distribution ckt. a new eaarth leakage protection relay is installed the then in cirtain situation it might trip. Just a guess. vtingole

Comment: Is this leakage protection relay small enough to be attached through an existing outlet? Because the maintenance guy said that he needed to access an outlet to put a "device" in to prevent the blackouts. Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that 98% of the things the maintenance guy said were utter codswallop.

Comment: relay is small but wiring is a  bit complex. vtingole